# Foundation: How can I get labels next to checkboxes?

Tags: zurb-foundation

As an experiment for experience and whatnot I'm trying to convert my Bootstrap website to Foundation.

I cannot see how to get checkbox labels on the right of the checkbox.

### Screenshot

[image]

### Code

```
    <!-- Registration Form -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="containerReg">
            <div class="twelve columns">            
                <div class="six columns">                           
                    <div class="reglayer">
                        <div class="twelve columns">
                            <!-- Registration Form -->
                            <h6>Chat now, it's free! </h6>      
                                <form action="client/index" method="post" target="_blank">    
                                 <div class="row">
                                    <div class="three mobile-one columns">
                                        <label class="right inline">Nickname:</label>
                                    </div>
                                        <div class="nine mobile-four columns">
                                        <input name="nickname" type="text" />
                                    </div>
                                 </div>                     
                                 <div class="row">
                                    <div class="three mobile-one columns">
                                        <label class="right inline">Gender:</label>
                                    </div>
                                        <div class="nine mobile-four columns">
      <input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="Female" id="Female"><label for="Female">Female</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="Male" id="Male"><label for="Male">Male</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="three mobile-one columns">
                                        <label class="right inline">Room:</label>
                                    </div>
                                        <div class="nine mobile-four columns">
      <input type="checkbox" name="channel" value="channel1" id="channel1"><label for="channel1">channel1</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="channel" value="channel2" id="channel2"><label for="channel2">channel2</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <p class="terms"> I am 18 years of age or older and have read and agree to obide by the Terms and Conditions</p>    
                                </form>
                                <!-- Submit Button -->
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="eleven columns centered"><a href="#" class="radius button">Connect to chat</a></div>
                                </div>                                      
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Spacer Columns -->
                <div class="five columns"></div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

### Question

How can I get it so that:

Gender row is like:

```
[] Female    [] Male
```

(spaced correctly to the text input above)

and

Room row is like:

```
[] channel1
[] channel 2
```

Comment: Which version of Foundation is this? It looks like quiet an old one you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the input inside the label itself

```
<label for="channel1"><input type="checkbox" name="channel" value="channel1" id="channel1">channel1</label>
```